# appending sheet using xlwt (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwt

I am attempting to append a number of sheets from one excel file into a single sheet in another excel file.

My code looks like this:

```
rb2= xlrd.open_workbook(ValidationReport + "2.xlsx")

for sheet in rb2.sheets():
    rowx += 5
    w_sheet.write(rowx, colx, sheet)

wb.save(ValidationReport + ".xls")
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception: Unexpected data type class 'xlrd.sheet.Sheet'
```

When I replace the sheet object with a string, that string will write to the desired file once for every sheet in my read file. Is there a way to write the contents of a single sheet to the bottom of a different excel file using xlwt?

Comment: The problem is you are supplying a [`Worksheet` object](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966) to the `label` argument of the `write()` method. The list of objects that can be written using that method are found in the documentation (e.g. a `str`, a `xlwt.Formula`, etc etc). The `Worksheet` object isn't on that list. You have to write *pieces* of that worksheet object  - such as the specific cells you want to copy in the source worksheet, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are not new to Python, this may seem like a no brainer, but for somebody like me, it took a while to figure out.

It is SO MUCH easier to try and manipulate csv files than excel files, and once I made the switch over, things moved much more quickly.

My new code looks something like this:

```
        df["Iflag"] = df.Independent.where((df.Independent == 0) | (df.Independent == 1 )).notnull().astype(int)
            Iflag = df[df.Iflag == 0]
            pd.DataFrame(Iflag, columns=["ID","Independent"]).to_csv(my.csv, mode='ab')
```